# Extracting string that is present in one string and not other

Tags: c#, string

I have two strings:

```
string strone="what is your name?"
string strtwo="what is your name? what is your school name?"
```

Any of the strings could be greater here. What I need is to extract string from `strtwo` which is not in `strone`.

What I have tried is this:

```
IEnumerable<string> str=strtwo.Except(strone); //(returns only first character ie w)
```

I tried converting both `strone` and `strtwo` to string arrays but looping through each string one by one won't provide solution as `strone` may contain other characters in between.

What i require is to extract the entire string sequentially in `strtwo` that is not in `strone`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `string diff = strtwo.Replace(strone,"")` ?

Comment: ya thanks this works fine... but i'm looking for something like finer solution where strone could be anything, greater or smaller but what matters is that string in strtwo that is not in strone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your looking for something that compares more than just the First part of the strings and shows the diff on the end then have a look at the [Diff Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13326/An-O-ND-Difference-Algorithm-for-C), but basically your looking for [This Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm)

However if you are just looking for the difference on the end of a string look at @dasblinkenlight solution

Answer (score 3):

you can try to extract the text from the second string in this fashion

```
string diff = strtwo.Replace(strone,"");
```

This should output you `" what is your school name?"` which is what you are looking out for else please do update the question with other example/cases.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is using `Replace`:

```
string strone="what is your name?";
string strtwo="what is your name? what is your school name?";

string finalStr = strtwo.Replace(strone, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string strone="what is your name?"
string strtwo="what is your name? what is your school name?"

string extractedString = strtwo.Replace(strone, "");
```

Comment: `Replace` won't go kaboooom!  if the Replacement text is not found, you can avoid the contains check

Comment: @V4Vendetta yes your right cant help it, me defensive by nature :)

Answer (score 1):

why not looking at the result of

```
strtwo.Split(new String[]{strone}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

?